# Cronjob is not running

Tags: macos, cron

I created a cronjob and set it to run at 6:00 am everyday but it doesn't run.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with this.

```
00 06 * * * . /Users/admin/.bash_profile; . /Users/admin/.bashrc; ruby /Users/admin/file.rb; ruby /Users/admin/another_file.rb

# standup timers
45 8 * * 1-5 /Applications/Alinof\ Timer.app/Contents/MacOS/Alinof\ Timer  [SetHours=00, SetMinutes=10, Start]
55 8 * * 1-5 /Applications/Alinof\ Timer.app/Contents/MacOS/Alinof\ Timer  [SetHours=00, SetMinutes=5, Start]
0,15 9 * * 1-5 /Applications/Alinof\ Timer.app/Contents/MacOS/Alinof\ Timer  [SetHours=00, SetMinutes=15, Start]

# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: store

# End Whenever generated tasks for: store
```

I also ran `ps aux | grep cron` and got this.

```
$ ps aux | grep cron
    58   ??  Ss     0:08.36 /usr/sbin/cron
    59844 s004  S+     0:00.00 grep cron
```

I can't run commands `service cron start` or `service cron restart`.

Here is the output from running them.

```
service: This command still works, but it is deprecated. Please use launchctl(8) instead.
service: failed to start the 'cron' service
```

Comment: What did you find out about `launchctl`?

Comment: @ScottHunter I haven't and can't currently. I'll post the result assuming it doesn't help but after editing the cronjob the terminal outputs "crontab: installing new crontab". But the issue here is that the cronjob isn't running?

Comment: You might try using full paths instead of relative ones.

Comment: @ScottHunter I also tried that on the first invocation of `ruby`. I had put the path to `/Users/admin/.rbenv/shims/ruby` and changed the time to the some time in the very near future and it still didn't run.

Comment: do you get anything when you type in "`crontab -l`"?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann it's the same thing as what I posted. The first block. It's listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided instead of running `. /Users/admin/.bash_profile; . /Users/admin/.bashrc; ruby /Users/admin/file.rb; ruby /Users/admin/another_file.rb` that I would put it inside of shell script and execute `/bin/sh file.sh`. Still not sure why the other way didn't work.